# how do you parse a sysmon file to extract certain information using R?

Tags: regex, r, parsing, pcre

I am trying to read bunch of this type of files using R to parse out the information and put the data in a data frame like format:

this is the contents of the file:

```
    last_run                        current_run                     seconds     
 ------------------------------- ------------------------------- ----------- 
             Jul  4 2016  7:17AM             Jul  4 2016  7:21AM         226 


Engine Utilization (Tick %)   User Busy   System Busy    I/O Busy        Idle
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  ThreadPool : syb_default_pool                                                 
   Engine 0                         5.0 %         0.4 %      22.4 %      72.1 % 
   Engine 1                         3.9 %         0.5 %      22.8 %      72.8 % 
   Engine 2                         5.6 %         0.3 %      22.5 %      71.6 % 
   Engine 3                         5.1 %         0.4 %      22.7 %      71.8 % 

     -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Pool Summary        Total       336.1 %        25.6 %    1834.6 %    5803.8 % 
                    Average         4.2 %         0.3 %      22.9 %      72.5 % 

  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Server Summary      Total       336.1 %        25.6 %    1834.6 %    5803.8 % 
                    Average         4.2 %         0.3 %      22.9 %      72.5 % 

Transaction Profile
-------------------

  Transaction Summary             per sec      per xact       count  % of total
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
    Committed Xacts                 137.3           n/a       41198     n/a     

     Average Runnable Tasks            1 min         5 min      15 min  % of total
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  ThreadPool : syb_default_pool                                                 
   Global Queue                       0.0           0.0         0.0       0.0 %
   Engine 0                           0.0           0.1         0.1       0.6 %
   Engine 1                           0.0           0.0         0.0       0.0 %
   Engine 2                           0.2           0.1         0.1       2.6 %

  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------             
  Pool Summary        Total           7.2           5.9         6.1             
                    Average           0.1           0.1         0.1             

  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------             
  Server Summary      Total           7.2           5.9         6.1             
                    Average           0.1           0.1         0.1 

Device Activity Detail
  ----------------------

  Device:                                                                       
    /dev/vx/rdsk/sybaserdatadg/datadev_125                                         
    datadev_125                   per sec      per xact       count  % of total
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Total I/Os                          0.0           0.0           0       n/a   
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Total I/Os                          0.0           0.0           0       0.0 %


  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  Device:                                                                       
    /dev/vx/rdsk/sybaserdatadg/datadev_126                                         
    datadev_126                   per sec      per xact       count  % of total
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Total I/Os                          0.0           0.0           0       n/a   
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Total I/Os                          0.0           0.0           0       0.0 %


  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  Device:                                                                       
    /dev/vx/rdsk/sybaserdatadg/datadev_127                                         
    datadev_127                   per sec      per xact       count  % of total
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
    Reads                                                                       
      APF                             0.0           0.0           5       0.4 %
      Non-APF                         0.0           0.0           1       0.1 %
    Writes                            3.8           0.0        1128      99.5 %
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Total I/Os                          3.8           0.0        1134       0.1 %

  Mirror Semaphore Granted            3.8           0.0        1134     100.0 %
  Mirror Semaphore Waited             0.0           0.0           0       0.0 %

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

  Device:                                                                       
    /sybaser/database/sybaseR/dev/sybaseR.datadev_000                                    
    GPS_datadev_000               per sec      per xact       count  % of total
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
    Reads                                                                       
      APF                             7.9           0.0        2372      55.9 %
      Non-APF                         5.5           0.0        1635      38.6 %
    Writes                            0.8           0.0         233       5.5 %
  -------------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  ---------- 
  Total I/Os                         14.1           0.0        4240       0.3 %

  Mirror Semaphore Granted           14.1           0.0        4239     100.0 %
  Mirror Semaphore Waited             0.0           0.0           2       0.0 %
```

I need to capture "Jul  4 2016  7:21AM" as Date, 
from "Engine Utilization (Tick%) line, Server Summary ->Average "4.2%"

From "Transaction Profile" section ->Transaction Profile "count" entry.

so, my data frame should look something like this:

```
Date                     Cpu   Count
Jul  4 2016  7:21AM      4.2   41198
```

Can somebody help me how to parse this file to get these output?

I have tried something like this:

```
read.table(text=readLines("file.txt")[count.fields("file.txt", blank.lines.skip=FALSE) == 9])
```

to get this line:

```
Average         4.2 %         0.3 %      22.9 %      72.5 %
```

But I want to be able to only extract Average right after

Engine Utilization (Tick %), since there could be many lines that start with Average. The Average line that shows up right after Engine Utilization (Tick %), is the one I want.

How do I put that in this line to extract this information from this file:

```
read.table(text=readLines("file.txt")[count.fields("file.txt", blank.lines.skip=FALSE) == 9])
```

Can I use grep in this read.table line to search for certain characters?

Comment: NB there is an ambiguity in your problem description. At one point you ask for  "from Engine Utilization (Tick%) line, Server Summary ->Average 4.2%". Later you ask for "The Average line that shows up right after Engine Utilization (Tick %), is the one I want." The latter refers to the "Pool Summary Average". The way my solution below is written at the moment, it assumes the 2nd of these criteria. Can you clarify in the question which of these lines is the one you want.

Comment: If you could read the whole file into a string variable, you could run a regex on it to extract just the stuff you need. I don't know R, so I don't know if it can read into a variable or do regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%%%% Shot 1 -- got something working

```
extract <- function(filenam="file.txt"){
    txt <- readLines(filenam)

    ## date of current run:
    ## assumed to be on 2nd line following the first line matching "current_run"
    ii <- 2 + grep("current_run",txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_current_run <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    date_current_run <- paste(line_current_run[5:8], collapse=" ")


    ## Cpu:
    ## assumed to be on line following the first line matching "Server Summary"
    ## which comes after the first line matching "Engine Utilization ..."
    jj <- grep("Engine Utilization (Tick %)", txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    ii <- grep("Server Summary",txt, fixed=TRUE)
    ii <- 1 + min(ii[ii>jj])
    line_Cpu <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    Cpu <- line_Cpu[2]


    ## Count:
    ## assumed to be on 2nd line following the first line matching "Transaction Summary"
    ii <- 2 + grep("Transaction Summary",txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_count <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    count <- line_count[5]

    data.frame(Date=date_current_run, Cpu=Cpu, Count=count, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

print(extract("file.txt"))

##file.list <- dir("./")
file.list <- rep("file.txt",3)
merged <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file.list, extract))

print(merged)

file.list <- rep("file.txt",2000)
print(system.time(merged <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file.list, extract))))
## runs in about 2.5 secs on my laptop
```

%%% Shot 2: 1st attempt to extract a (potentially variable) number of device columns

```
extractv2 <- function(filenam="file2.txt"){
    txt <- readLines(filenam)

    ## date of current run:
    ## assumed to be on 2nd line following the first line matching "current_run"
    ii <- 2 + grep("current_run",txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_current_run <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    date_current_run <- paste(line_current_run[5:8], collapse=" ")


    ## Cpu:
    ## assumed to be on line following the first line matching "Server Summary"
    ## which comes after the first line matching "Engine Utilization ..."
    jj <- grep("Engine Utilization (Tick %)", txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    ii <- grep("Server Summary",txt, fixed=TRUE)
    ii <- 1 + min(ii[ii>jj])
    line_Cpu <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    Cpu <- line_Cpu[2]


    ## Count:
    ## assumed to be on 2nd line following the first line matching "Transaction Summary"
    ii <- 2 + grep("Transaction Summary",txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_count <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    count <- line_count[5]


    ## Total I/Os
    ## 1. Each line "Device:" is assumed to be the header of a block of lines
    ##    containing info about a single device (there are 4 such blocks
    ##    in your example);
    ## 2. each block is assumed to contain one or more lines matching
    ##    "Total I/Os";
    ## 3. the relevant count data is assumed to be contained in the last
    ##    of such lines (at column 4), for each block.
    ## Approach: loop on the line numbers of those lines matching "Device:"
    ## to get: A. counts; B. device names
    ii_block_dev <- grep("Device:", txt, fixed=TRUE)
    ii_lines_IOs <- grep("Total I/Os", txt, fixed=TRUE)
    nblocks <- length(ii_block_dev)
    ## A. get counts for each device
    ## for each block, select *last* line matching "Total I/Os"
    ii_block_dev_aux <- c(ii_block_dev, Inf) ## just a hack to get a clean code
    ii_lines_IOs_dev <- sapply(1:nblocks, function(block){
        ## select matching liens to "Total I/Os" within each block
        IOs_per_block <- ii_lines_IOs[ ii_lines_IOs > ii_block_dev_aux[block  ] &
                                       ii_lines_IOs < ii_block_dev_aux[block+1]
                                   ]
        tail(IOs_per_block, 1) ## get the last line of each block (if more than one match)
    })
    lines_IOs <- lapply(txt[ii_lines_IOs_dev], function(strng){
        Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(strng," ")[[1]])
    })
    IOs_counts <- sapply(lines_IOs, function(v) v[5])
    ## B. get device names:
    ## assumed to be on lines following each "Device:" match
    ii_devices <- 1 + ii_block_dev
    device_names <- sapply(ii_devices, function(ii){
        Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    })
    ## Create a data.frame with "device_names" as column names and "IOs_counts" as
    ## the values of a single row.
    ## Sorting the device names by order() will help produce the same column names
    ## if different sysmon files list the devices in different order
    ord <- order(device_names)
    devices <- as.data.frame(structure(as.list(IOs_counts[ord]), names=device_names[ord]),
                             check.names=FALSE) ## Prevent R from messing with our device names

    data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE,
               Date=date_current_run, Cpu=Cpu, Count=count, devices)
}
print(extractv2("file2.txt"))


## WATCH OUT:
## merging will ONLY work if all devices have the same names across sysmon files!!
file.list <- rep("file2.txt",3)
merged <- do.call("rbind", lapply(file.list, extractv2))
print(merged)
```

%%%%%%% Shot 3: extract two tables, one with a single row, and a second with a variable number of rows (depending on the which devices are listed in each sysmon file).

```
extractv3 <- function(filenam="file2.txt"){
    txt <- readLines(filenam)

    ## date of current run:
    ## assumed to be on 2nd line following the first line matching "current_run"
    ii <- 2 + grep("current_run",txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_current_run <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    date_current_run <- paste(line_current_run[5:8], collapse=" ")


    ## Cpu:
    ## assumed to be on line following the first line matching "Server Summary"
    ## which comes after the first line matching "Engine Utilization ..."
    jj <- grep("Engine Utilization (Tick %)", txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    ii <- grep("Server Summary",txt, fixed=TRUE)
    ii <- 1 + min(ii[ii>jj])
    line_Cpu <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    Cpu <- line_Cpu[2]


    ## Count:
    ## assumed to be on 2nd line following the first line matching "Transaction Summary"
    ii <- 2 + grep("Transaction Summary",txt, fixed=TRUE)[1]
    line_count <- Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
    count <- line_count[5]

    ## first part of output: fixed three-column structure
    fixed <-  data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                         Date=date_current_run, Cpu=Cpu, Count=count)

    ## Total I/Os
    ## 1. Each line "Device:" is assumed to be the header of a block of lines
    ##    containing info about a single device (there are 4 such blocks
    ##    in your example);
    ## 2. each block is assumed to contain one or more lines matching
    ##    "Total I/Os";
    ## 3. the relevant count data is assumed to be contained in the last
    ##    of such lines (at column 4), for each block.
    ## Approach: loop on the line numbers of those lines matching "Device:"
    ## to get: A. counts; B. device names
    ii_block_dev <- grep("Device:", txt, fixed=TRUE)
    if(length(ii_block_dev)==0){
        variable <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                               date_current_run=date_current_run,
                               device_names=NA, IOs_counts=NA)
    }else{
        ii_lines_IOs <- grep("Total I/Os", txt, fixed=TRUE)
        nblocks <- length(ii_block_dev)
        if(length(ii_block_dev)==0){
            sprintf("WEIRD datapoint at date %s: I have %d devices but 0 I/O lines??")
            ##stop()
        }
        ## A. get counts for each device
        ## for each block, select *last* line matching "Total I/Os"
        ii_block_dev_aux <- c(ii_block_dev, Inf) ## just a hack to get a clean code
        ii_lines_IOs_dev <- sapply(1:nblocks, function(block){
            ## select matching lines to "Total I/Os" within each block
            IOs_per_block <- ii_lines_IOs[ ii_lines_IOs > ii_block_dev_aux[block  ] &
                                           ii_lines_IOs < ii_block_dev_aux[block+1]
                                          ]
            tail(IOs_per_block, 1) ## get the last line of each block (if more than one match)
        })
        lines_IOs <- lapply(txt[ii_lines_IOs_dev], function(strng){
            Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(strng," ")[[1]])
        })
        IOs_counts <- sapply(lines_IOs, function(v) v[5])
        ## B. get device names:
        ## assumed to be on lines following each "Device:" match
        ii_devices <- 1 + ii_block_dev
        device_names <- sapply(ii_devices, function(ii){
            Filter(function(v) v!="", strsplit(txt[ii]," ")[[1]])
        })
        ## Create a data.frame with three columns: date, device, counts
        variable <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                               date_current_run=rep(date_current_run, length(IOs_counts)),
                               device_names=device_names, IOs_counts=IOs_counts)
    }
    list(fixed=fixed, variable=variable)
}
print(extractv3("file2.txt"))


file.list <- c("file.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt")
res <- lapply(file.list, extractv3)

fixed.merged <- do.call("rbind", lapply(res, function(r) r$fixed))
print(fixed.merged)

variable.merged <- do.call("rbind", lapply(res, function(r) r$variable))
print(variable.merged)
```

Comment: thank you it worked like a charm. Your answer gave me great ideas about parsing different files.

Comment: I know you already answered this question. If you don't mind, I have one more addition. I've added to the end of the original post. I also like to get this value from this file: "Device:                                                                       
    /sybaser/database/sybaseR/dev/sybaseR.temp10_logdev_001" as the column name and "Total I/Os                          0.9           0.0         262       0.0 %" 262 from this line. There are bunch of these entries and like to create a column for each device entry.

Comment: would you be able to chat?

Comment: Yes I can chat. As a matter of fact, I have not understood your last question and I could not find, within the original post, the new entries that you mention in your comment.

Comment: would you be able to join this chat:https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121644/sysmon

Comment: sorry I just added the new entries. Systmon file has device statistics (file system). For each file system, I would like to get Total IOs per sec. There are multiple entries (fileystem) in each sysmon file.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating text files can sometimes be easier using dedicated programs. E.g. `gawk` is specifically designed for finding patterns in text files and outputting data from them. We can use a short gawk script to get the required data to load into R. Note, each line of the script consists of a pattern to look for, followed by an action to take enclosed in`{}`. `NR` is a counter that counts number of lines read so far.

```
BEGIN                          {OFS = ""; ORS = ""}
/current_run/                  {dat_line = NR+2; cpu_done = 0}
/Server Summary/               {cpu_line = NR+1}
/Transaction Summary/          {cnt_line = NR+2}
NR == dat_line                 {print "'",$5," ",$6," ",$7," ",$8,"' "}
NR == cpu_line && cpu_done==0  {print $2," "; cpu_done = 1}
NR == cnt_line                 {print $5,"\n"}
```

Save this script with the name "ext.awk", then extract all the data files into an R data frame (assuming they are all located in one folder and have the extension `.txt`) with

```
df <- read.table(text=system("gawk -f ext.awk *.txt", T), col.names = c("Date","Cpu","Count"))
```

NB, gawk comes ready installed on most Linux versions. On windows you may need to install it from `http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm`

Answer (score 0):

**For reading the files**
Here I am assuming CSV as file type.
For others please visit
 **http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import**

```
>utilization <- read.csv(file="",head=TRUE)
>serverSummary <-read.csv(file="",head=TRUE)
>transcProfile <- read.csv(file="",head=TRUE)
```

**==>merge only accepts two arguments**

```
>data <- merge(utilization,serverSummary)
>dataframe <-merge(data,transcProfile)
```

**now you will have all the columns in dataframe**

```
>dataframe
```

u can see all the columns in dataframe

**Extarct the columns as per required**
==>The subset( ) function is the easiest way to select variables and observations

```
>subset(dataframe,select=c("last_run","Average","Transaction Profile")
```

Now you can write it to CSV or any file type

```
>write.csv(dataframe, file = "MyData.csv")
```

For merging all the files together

```
multmerge = function(mypath){
filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=T)})
Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, datalist)
```

After running the code to define the function, you are all set to use it. The function takes a path. This path should be the name of a folder that contains all of the files you would like to read and merge together and only those files you would like to merge. With this in mind, I have two tips:

Before you use this function, my suggestion is to create a new folder in a short directory (for example, the path for this folder could be “C://R//mergeme“) and save all of the files you would like to merge in that folder.
In addition, make sure that the column that will do the matching is formatted the same way (and has the same name) in each of the files.
Suppose you saved your 20 files into the mergeme folder at “C://R//mergeme” and you would like to read and merge them. To use my function, you use the following syntax:

```
mymergeddata = multmerge(“C://R//mergeme”)
```

After running this command, you have a fully merged data frame with all of your variables matched to each other

Now you can subset the dataframe as per required columns.

Comment: this is taking a very long time to complete as I am keep merging the files and I have thousands of files to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Use `readLines` or `stringi::stri_read_lines` to read the contents of the file as a character vector.  The latter is typically faster, but not as mature, and occasionally breaks on unusual content.

```
lines <- readLines("the file name")
```

For fast regular expresssion matching, `stringi` is typically the best choice.  `rebus.datetimes` allows you you to generate a regular expression from a `strptime` date format string.

#### Finding the current run date

The line of which `current_run` appears is found with:

```
library(stringi)
library(rebus.datetimes)

i_current_run <- which(stri_detect_fixed(lines, "current_run"))
```

To extract the dates, this code only looks at the 2nd line after the one where current run is found, but the code is vectorizable, so you can easily look at all the lines if you have files where that assumption doesn't hold.

```
date_format <- "%b%t%d%t%Y%t%H:%M%p"
rx_date <- rebus.datetimes::datetime(date_format, io = "input")
extracted_dates <- stri_extract_all_regex(lines[i_current_run + 2], rx_date)
current_run_date <- strptime(
  extracted_dates[[1]][2], date_format, tz = "UTC"
)
## [1] "2016-07-04 07:21:00 UTC"
```

#### Finding the % user busy

The "Engine Utilization" section is found via

```
i_engine_util <- which(
  stri_detect_fixed(lines, "Engine Utilization (Tick %)")
)
```

We want the first instance of "Server Summary" that comes after this line.

```
i_server_summary <- i_engine_util + 
  min(which(
    stri_detect_fixed(lines[(i_engine_util + 1):n_lines], "Server Summary")
  ))
```

Use a regular expression to extract the number from the next line.

```
user_busy <- as.numeric(
  stri_extract_first_regex(lines[i_server_summary + 1], "[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9])")
)
## [1] 4.2
```

#### Finding the count of committed xacts

The "Committed Xacts" line is

```
i_comm_xacts <- which(stri_detect_fixed(lines, "Committed Xacts"))
```

The count value is a set of digits surrounded by space.

```
xacts_count <- as.integer(
  stri_extract_all_regex(lines[i_comm_xacts], "(?<= )[0-9]+(?= )")
)
## [1] 41198
```

#### Combining the results

```
data.frame(
  Date = current_run_date,
  CPU = user_busy,
  Count = xacts_count
)
```